# Not able to assert that mongoose save function was called in a unit test

Tags: mongoose, mocha.js, sinon

I've looked through several posts related to unit testing mocha/sinon with mongoose but I still haven't gotten it to work to verify that the save method is called on my mongoose model. I want to test that order.save was called in my controller. The error I get is that order.save is not a function in the production code orderController.js.

I've tried a few different ways but I haven't been able to assert that save is called.

A simple model:

**orderModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const orderModel = new Schema({
    location: {type: String},
    cost: {type: Number},
    status: {type: String, default: 'unpaid'}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderModel);

The controller is the production code that I want to test
orderController.js
var orderController = function (Order) {

    var post = function (req, res) {
        var order = new Order();
        order.save();
        res.status(201);
    }

    return {
        post: post
    }
}

module.exports = orderController;
```

This is the spec file. I want to verify that save was called, it doesn't matter if it's a stub, spy or a mock. I just haven't been able to assert after the call to ctrl.post that it was called

**orderController.spec.js**

```
var sinon = require('sinon'),
chai = require('chai'),
expect = chai.expect,
mongoose = require('mongoose');

describe('Order Controller', function() {

    it('should save an order', function() {
        var Order = require('../../app/models/orderModel');
        var orderStub = sinon.stub(Order.prototype, 'save');
        var ctrl = require('../../app/controllers/orderController')(orderStub);

        var req, res;
        req = res = {};
        res.status = sinon.spy();
        ctrl.post(req, res);
        sinon.assert.called(orderStub.prototype.save);
    });
});
```

Comment: Just some quick reformatting of code, you might want to look into the way that the "markdown" markup language works since this is what is used by SO, indenting 4 spaces makes it a code block where you've put in a regular paragraph of text ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work with some help I received elsewhere.

**orderController.spec.js**

```
describe('Order Controller', function() {
    it('should save an order', sinon.test(function(done) {
        var saveStub = sinon.stub();
        var Order = this.stub(models, 'Order');
        Order.returns({
            save: saveStub
        });         

        const ctrl = require('../../app/controllers/orderController') (Order);

        ctrl.post(req, res);

        sinon.assert.calledOnce(saveStub);
   });
```